# How to separate a table cell into two equal parts with different background via css?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have a 2x2 html table. In one of the fields of the table I have two subfields. Both of those subfields are supposed to take together the entire area of the table cell.

Is there a straightforward result to achieve this via CSS?

Comment: Some code would be appreciated. Surely you should know the basic rules by now?

Comment: @Paulie_D http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic does not say that every question has to have code. In this case I think the image illustrates my issue perfectly well.

Comment: Are the table cells fixed size or variable size?

Comment: @Christian No...but you're asking us to offer suggestions without knowing the structure. Anything we might offer could be invalidated if it doesn't fit what you already have. Simple logic would suggest some HTML is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option One**

Using divs you could separate a table cell without the need for a colspan.

`display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: top` can keep them in line.

[Example!](http://jsbin.com/taxuf/1/edit)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div></div><div></div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: solid 2px #111;
}

td {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #FFF;
    border: solid 2px #111;
}

td div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;  
    vertical-align: top;
}

td div:first-child {
    background: green;
}
```

---

**Option Two**

Using a colspan.

[Example with colspan](http://jsbin.com/pazin/1/edit)

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="test"></td>
        <td class="test"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: solid 2px #111;
}

td {
    height: 100px;
    background: #FFF;
    border: solid 2px #111;
    width: 50px;
}

tr td:last-child {
    width: 100px;
}

.test {
    background: blue;
}
.test:first-child {
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to create table in table for that purpose,
which is IMO the best solution, which is more scalable.

```
<table>
    <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><tr>
        <tr><td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="background-color:orange;">5</td>
                    <td style="background-color:blue;">6</td></tr></table></td><td>4</td>
</table>
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO - Table in Table](http://jsfiddle.net/jn8db0u5/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child {
    position: relative;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child:after,
tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: -1;
    margin: auto;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child:before {
    background: cyan;
    left: 0;
    right: 50%;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child:after {
    background: blue;
    left: 50%;
}
```

The use of generated content makes additional markup unnecessary.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wck4j6g4/